# How can I add the multi-turn prompt in the webchat?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I added multi-turn prompts to my qna, and they work in the qna website, but when trying in the webchat the prompts don't show up.

Do they work in the webchat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the result as a card like the QnA test portal does, you need to convert the result to an Adaptive Card. See the code snippets below.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Bot Code - onMessage - Node**

```
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {

  const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);

  if (qnaResults[0]) {
      const { answer, context: { prompts }} = qnaResults[0];

      let reply;
      if (prompts.length) {

        const card = {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "body": [
              {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": answer,
                  wrap: true
              }
          ],
          "actions": prompts.map(({ displayText }) => ({ type: "Action.Submit", title: displayText, data: displayText })),
          "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
          "version": "1.1"
        }

        reply = { attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] };
      } else {
        reply = answer;
      }

      await context.sendActivity(reply);

  // If no answers were returned from QnA Maker, reply with help.
  } else {
      await context.sendActivity('No QnA Maker answers were found.');
  }

  await next();
});
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using C#, but I will try that method, thank you

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at this [AdaptiveCards Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/) since you are using C#. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as an accepted answer so I can move it off of my support tracker. If you are still struggling to get it to work, please let me know what other questions you have.

Answer (score -1):

I have answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367963/5209435).

Basically you need to build your own HTTP call to your QnA Maker KB instead of using the built in methods as per [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore/Helpers/QnAService.cs#L25-L51):

```
public async Task<QnAResult[]> QueryQnAServiceAsync(string query, QnABotState qnAcontext)
{
    var requestUrl = $"{_endpoint.Host}/knowledgebases/{_endpoint.KnowledgeBaseId}/generateanswer";
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
    var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        new
        {
            question = query,
            top = _options.Top,
            context = qnAcontext,
            strictFilters = _options.StrictFilters,
            metadataBoost = _options.MetadataBoost,
            scoreThreshold = _options.ScoreThreshold,
        }, Formatting.None);

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"EndpointKey {_endpoint.EndpointKey}");
    request.Content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


    var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnAResultList>(contentString);

    return result.Answers;
}
```

Then inspect the result for any prompts, and act accordingly:

```
var query = inputActivity.Text;           
var qnaResult = await _qnaService.QueryQnAServiceAsync(query, new QnABotState());
var qnaAnswer = qnaResult[0].Answer;
var prompts = qnaResult[0].Context?.Prompts;

if (prompts == null || prompts.Length < 1)
{
    outputActivity = MessageFactory.Text(qnaAnswer);
}
else
{
    outputActivity = CardHelper.GetHeroCard(qnaAnswer, prompts);
}

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(outputActivity);
```

**Note:** The code above for "acting accordingly" will only work for a single level of prompts, as per my answer that I linked at the top. If you want to support multiple levels of prompts then you will have to implement as state system as per [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore) - see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367963/5209435) for more details.

**Note2:** As mentioned in a comment below, using the above approach (HeroCard) could end up with a truncated title if the text is too long. To avoid this you could use [Adaptive Dialogs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog#readme) or [Adaptive Cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards/Bots/AdaptiveCardsBot.cs).

**EDIT**

Based on [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore)

You should be able to achieve a single level of prompts with something like this:

QnAResult.cs

```
    public class QnAResult
    {
        public string[] Questions { get; set; }

        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public double Score { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Source { get; set; }

        public QnAMetadata[] Metadata { get; set; }

        public QnAContext Context { get; set; }
    }
```

QnAResultList.cs

```
public class QnAResultList
    {
        public QnAResult[] Answers { get; set; }
    }
```

IQnAService.cs

```
    public interface IQnAService
    {
        Task<QnAResult[]> QueryQnAServiceAsync(string query, QnABotState qnAcontext, QnAMakerEndpoint qnAMakerEndpoint);
    }
```

QnAService.cs

```
public class QnAService : IQnAService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public QnAService(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task<QnAResult[]> QueryQnAServiceAsync(string query, QnABotState qnAcontext, QnAMakerEndpoint qnAMakerEndpoint)
        {
            var options = new QnAMakerOptions
            {
                Top = 3
            };

            var hostname = qnAMakerEndpoint.Host;

            var endpoint = new QnAMakerEndpoint
            {
                KnowledgeBaseId = qnAMakerEndpoint.KnowledgeBaseId,
                EndpointKey = qnAMakerEndpoint.EndpointKey,
                Host = hostname
            };

            var requestUrl = $"{endpoint.Host}/knowledgebases/{endpoint.KnowledgeBaseId}/generateanswer";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
            var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new
                {
                    question = query,
                    top = options.Top,
                    context = qnAcontext,
                    strictFilters = options.StrictFilters,
                    metadataBoost = options.MetadataBoost,
                    scoreThreshold = options.ScoreThreshold,
                }, Formatting.None);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"EndpointKey {endpoint.EndpointKey}");
            request.Content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


            var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnAResultList>(contentString);

            return result.Answers;
        }
    }
```

CardHelper.cs

```
    public class CardHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get Hero card
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cardTitle">Title of the card</param>
        /// <param name="prompts">List of suggested prompts</param>
        /// <returns>Message activity</returns>
        public static Activity GetHeroCardWithPrompts(string cardTitle, QnAPrompts[] prompts)
        {
            var chatActivity = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            var buttons = new List<CardAction>();

            var sortedPrompts = prompts.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayOrder);
            foreach (var prompt in sortedPrompts)
            {
                buttons.Add(
                    new CardAction()
                    {
                        Value = prompt.DisplayText,
                        Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                        Title = prompt.DisplayText
                    });
            }

            var plCard = new HeroCard()
            {
                Title = cardTitle,
                Subtitle = string.Empty,
                Buttons = buttons
            };

            var attachment = plCard.ToAttachment();

            chatActivity.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            return (Activity)chatActivity;
        }
    }
```

MyBot.cs HandleQnA()

```
QnAResult[] qnaResults =  await _qnAService.QueryQnAServiceAsync(context.Activity.Text, new QnABotState(), _qnAMakerEndpoint);

                if (qnaResults.Any())
                {
                    // Get result by highest confidence
                    QnAResult highestRankedResult = qnaResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First();
                    string answer = highestRankedResult.Answer;

                    QnAPrompts[] prompts = highestRankedResult.Context?.Prompts;

                    if (prompts == null || prompts.Length < 1)
                    {
                        await context.SendActivityAsync(answer, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await context.SendActivityAsync(CardHelper.GetHeroCardWithPrompts(answer, prompts), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    }
                }
```

The NuGet packages I am using are:

[image: packages]

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend using a hero card since the title attribute has a character limit in Web Chat, and if the answer is too long, the response will get truncated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @tdurnford, I have added 'Note2" to my answer.

Comment: As I am only using one level prompts, is there anyway of the prompts in the answer without passing for all that steps?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues see my edit to my answer and let me know how you go.

Comment: Thank you, but I don´t have much time to finish this project so I find a different way of making the prompt