# Getting Facebook Messenger to show QnA Follow-Up Prompts in BotFramework v4 using Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to figure out how to get Facebook Messenger to show follow-up prompts from QnA Maker using BotFramework v4 and Node.js.

I've managed to get the follow-up prompts showing in WebChat:[image]

I managed this after following the great advice from Matt Stannett in this thread:
[How to implement cards in a QnA question which has follow up prompts and uses them in the cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185169/how-to-implement-cards-in-a-qna-question-which-has-follow-up-prompts-and-uses-th/56367963#56367963)

However, when it comes to getting them to appear in Facebook Messenger, I'm really struggling.

I was hoping it would be as straightforward as defining some channelData for Facebook Quick Replies in my onMessage code, as I just need Facebook to pass back a simple text payload. I thought I could do it in a similar way I got the prompts showing for Webchat, code below:

```
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
        this.logger.log('Processing a Message Activity');

        const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);

        // Show choices if the Facebook Payload from ChannelData is not handled
        if (!await this.processFacebookPayload(context, context.activity.channelData)) {
            if (context.activity.channelId == 'facebook') {
              if (qnaResults[0]) {
                const { answer, context: { prompts }} = qnaResults[0];

                let reply;
                if (prompts.length) {

                  const quickReply = {
                    channelData: {
                      "messaging_type":"RESPONSE",
                      "message":{
                        "text":"test1", //answer,
                        "quick_replies":[
                          {
                            "content_type":"text",
                            "title":"test2",//prompts.map({ displayText }),
                            "payload":"test3",//prompts.map({ displayText })
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }

                    reply = quickReply;
                  } else {
                    reply = answer;
                  }

                  await context.sendActivity(reply);

              // If no answers were returned from QnA Maker, reply with help.
              } else {
                  await context.sendActivity('I\'m sorry, I don\'t have an answer for that. Please ask me something else, such as: \n\n "What Is Mental Health?" \n\n "What Is NeuroDiversity" \n\n "Help"');
              }

            } else {

            // If an answer was received from QnA Maker, send the answer back to the user.
            if (qnaResults[0]) {
              const { answer, context: { prompts }} = qnaResults[0];

              let reply;
              if (prompts.length) {

                const card = {
                  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                  "body": [
                    {
                      "type": "TextBlock",
                      "text": answer,
                      wrap: true
                    }
                ],
                "actions": prompts.map(({ displayText }) => ({ type: "Action.Submit", title: displayText, data: displayText })),
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version": "1.1"
                }

                  reply = { attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] };
                } else {
                  reply = answer;
                }

                await context.sendActivity(reply);

            // If no answers were returned from QnA Maker, reply with help.
            } else {
                await context.sendActivity('I\'m sorry, I don\'t have an answer for that. Please ask me something else, such as: \n\n "What Is Mental Health?" \n\n "What Is NeuroDiversity" \n\n "Help"');
            }
            }

        }

        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
    });
```

This isn't working though. What I do get is QnA replies for any questions I ask that don't have a follow-up prompt set in QnA Maker, so I know that the IF statement is correctly identifying Facebook as a channel and that an answer has follow-up prompts associated with it. I think I just haven't got the code right for the quick replies in Facebook.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get some generic Quick Replies working by modifying my quickReply channelData:

```
const quickReply = {
                    channelData: {
                        text: answer,
                        quick_replies: [
                          {
                            content_type: "text",
                            title: "Prompt 1",
                            payload: "Prompt 1"
                          },{
                            content_type: "text",
                            title: "Prompt 2",
                            payload: "Prompt 2"
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                  }
```

You can then create a variable to insert the follow-up prompt into the channel data:

```
var qnaPrompts = null;
if(qnaResults[0].context != null){
   qnaPrompts = qnaResults[0].context.prompts;
}
```

Next you need to re-map the array to a new array in the correct format for quick replies:

```
var qnaPromptsArray = qnaPrompts.map(obj =>{
   return {content_type: "text", title: obj.displayText, payload: obj.displayText}
});
```

This now displays the QnA follow-up prompt as a quick reply in Facebook Messenger if you update quickReply as follows:

```
const quickReply = {
   channelData: {
      text: answer,
      quick_replies: qnaPromptsArray
   }
}
```

The final thing to work out is how to re-format the payload back to the QnA into a format that it accepts. To do this you need to adjust your turnContext to a string in Activity.Text as follows and then call the QnA:

```
turnContext.activity.text = quickReply.payload;
const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(turnContext);
```

Comment: It looks like there are some methods available for QnA when prompting for an answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamakerruntime/runtime/generateanswer

I believe I need to select the prompt I want to show using the displayOrder array and use displayText to show the prompt text.